# Is it possible render the scene in background thread in Android & OpengGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Now I derived a sub class from GLSurfaceView and init the Opengl es 2.0 ok, ready to render.
but i want to render the scene in a another thread aside in xxx.so writen by c, I tried the eglMakeCurrent but no luck, always get a error EGL_BAD_ACCESS.
I would like to draw a figure to describe the architecture i use.

```
Java:  GLSurfaceView(eglCreateContexture,CreateSurface)
```

__*_*_*Sureface Init Jni interface |*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___

NDK/C: Surface `Init(using eglGetCurrentDisplay()`and xxx to get display context surface and pass all those to native rendering thread)

Native rendering thread:(use `eglMakeCurrent()` and call glxxx function to render)

BUT it's not working!

so,i want to know if it is possible and how?

Comment: The surface will be destroyed when your program runs in the background.
So, you may fail to acess the eglSurface because it is invalid when you call eglMakeCurrent.